# Issue regarding Perl @INC path upgrade at build time

Tags: perl, rhel

I am trying to migrate from Perl 5.8.8 to Perl 5.10.1. (Basically RHEL 5 to RHEL 6.6 ) 
As per the install documentation provided by perl, at the time of configuring perl we can use "-Dotherlibdirs" to add additional directories in INC path variable.
At the time of building Perl 5.10.1, I am using this option to includes directories used in Perl 5.8.8.

For example

```
Actual Perl 5.10.1 INC list:
/usr/local/lib64/perl5
/usr/local/share/perl5
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
/usr/lib64/perl5
/usr/share/perl5
.

Expected Perl 5.10.1 INC list:
/usr/local/lib64/perl5
/usr/local/share/perl5
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
/usr/lib64/perl5
/usr/share/perl5
**/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8**  
.
```

So the configuration option will be

-Dotherlibdirs="/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8".

Having this option in configuration, build completes successfully but, after installing the RPM (created after build) and checking the output of "perl -V", added path is not visible in INC variable but "-Dotherlibdirs="/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8"" is visible in the configuration part of the output.

If anybody can help me out here !

Comment: Don't do that. Version specific stuff is for version specific stuff.

Comment: Is that means directories from previous version won't support in new version?

Comment: Perl installs modules in two sets of directories, the arch directory and the non-arch directory. The arch directory contain build- and version-specific installations. It's not safe to share these. (An arch directory will be of the form `version` or `version/archname`, e.g. `5.20.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi`.) While it's possible to share non-arch directories, it's not really a good either because the modules in that directory might have dependencies installed in arch directories. So while I don't know what your problem is, you're doing something you shouldn't be doing anyway.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to change the system Perl? Don't do that! Install the new Perl in a new directory using `-Dprefix`.

Comment: @ikegami: I understand the concept of arch and non-arch directories. My intention is to use custom (wrote by myself) perl modules to be used in perl 5.10.1 without changing there directory. In current installed perl 5.8.8 my modules are installed in "/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8" and after upgrading Perl to 5.10.1 the new INC variable doesn't include this path. So this is the reason behind my post. Note: There are other option available to update INC variable on runtime but I wants to do it on build time. Do you see any problem in this ?

Comment: Typically when you upgrade Perl, you re-install all of the modules for the new version, for the reasons ikegami mentioned above. Just re-install your modules for your new Perl version.

Comment: Re "I understand the concept of arch and non-arch directories", Then you know why you shouldn't be adding Perl 5.8's arch dir (`/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8`) to Perl 5.10's `@INC`.

Answer (score 0):

I prefere to have several perl installations in one directorie, not upgrade:

```
./Configure -des -Dprefix=/usr/local/perls/perl-5.09
./Configure -des -Dprefix=/usr/local/perls/perl-5.10
./Configure -des -Dprefix=/usr/local/perls/perl-5.x
```

They all have their own bin and modules directories.
then easy you may create a symlink for needed perl and all path will be correct.